# How to scrap data from website that uses cookies using scala scraper?

Tags: scala, web-scraping, cookies, jsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from website (https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa) but getting **403 (forbidden)**.

I'm using scala version 2.13.1, sbt version 1.2.8 and libraries ("net.ruippeixotog" %% "scala-scraper" % "3.0.0", "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.15.3").

**Code:**

```
object ScalaScraper extends App{
  val ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  val browser = new JsoupBrowser(userAgent = ua)
  val cookies:Map[String, String] = Map(
    "ASPSESSIONIDQSBCTBBT"->"...hidden...",
    "SnapABugHistory"-> "2#",
    "_gid"-> "GA1.2.21330449.1684823122",
    "_ga"-> "GA1.1.1109375111.1684582576",
    "SnapABugUserAlias"-> "%23",
    "SnapABugVisit"-> "5#1684831262",
    "_ga_HQHD139BDT"-> "JCOIme7hJX0DSttMQQc3uvRb_icNZBQvH0g2tUvLxtc-1684911558-0-Abyg2SfcN4woQn15jTpYcn/kDeufSxKdqD8uD6jsYBEdQu4mY8UIMLQDE1mUtZg3nWETRgWkY2nRUFjIDBfgCcM=",
    "__cf_bm" -> "H3NvJ691o76iMBYHNIe4CwVATgmGmjYA9lWrNHhhKTc-1684927933-0-AZGonJ9RWnTVvooeEvt+Dyfg8WuONDrKXxETWrnQdtVceatbTl0OSQX/OgyGAwGikHr7UnHrW9H4IeOzzytXqJo="
  )
  browser.setCookies("https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa", cookies)
  println("useragent " + browser.userAgent)
  val doc = browser.get("https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa?search=1&page=1&zip=15037&radius=20&language=16")
  println("document is {}", doc)
}
```

**Detail:**

I have added userAgent which is mentioned in the site (In Inspect/console/navigator.userAgent) and then I added the cookies which are mentioned in the site (In inspect/network/cookies). Then I try to scrap using **browser.get(url)**.

**Error:**

```
useragent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=[https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa?search=1&page=1&zip=15037&radius=20&language=16]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:366)
    at net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser.executeRequest(JsoupBrowser.scala:85)
    at net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser.$anonfun$executePipeline$3(JsoupBrowser.scala:96)
    at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)
    at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)
    at net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser.get(JsoupBrowser.scala:39)
    at scalaSc$.delayedEndpoint$scalaSc$1(ScrapWithSelenium.scala:80)
    at scalaSc$delayedInit$body.apply(ScrapWithSelenium.scala:62)
```

Where I am doing wrong? Am I adding userAgent and cookies in right way or there is another way to do this, in order to avoid 403?

Why website is not allowing to scrap data even after I've added the cookies?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: These cookies may be sensitive and give access to anyone to your account on the website. Don't publish cookie values publicly of you don't know what they're used for!

Comment: Did you try with cURL out of curiosity (you should have a "copy as cURL" in your browser to make it easier). Does the response 403 contain a body with additional details? It could be that the session Id cookie has an expiration time. Or it could something else. Anyway probably owner of the website doesn't want you to scrap it.

Answer (score 0):

If I execute a `curl` or even send a http request using `postman` to the url that is returning the `403`, it also gives me a the same status code. If I put that url in any browser (chrome, firefox, etc) it works and shows the web with no issues. Sounds like there could be some filter that doesn't let you scrap the web or the setup you are using is not the right one. Instead of directly hit the url with the query string, you could try to go to the web https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa, fill the form with the values you want such as `zip=15037` and `radius=20` and click on the `Search` button? That could work. It depends on how the configuration of the web.